# Extracting 'fields' and striping substrings

Tags: shell, substring

I have a list of file names that look like the following.

```
A006280002.40.D7A5A.msg
A006280002.41.C7E4E.msg
A006280002.42.16362.msg
A006280002.43.C4048.msg
A12960004.1.4D6AC.xls
K00976.1.81F42.pdf
```

I need to accomplish two things. Firstly, all these file names have as their prefix a code which indicates a client reference number. All client reference numbers start with a single letter but some as you can see have consistent zero padding of the number and some do not.

The client reference is the first part of the file name e.g. A00628. Hypothetically, someone may have however used variants like A0628 or A628. As per the above example data A12960004.1.4D6AC.xls has a client reference of A1296 and is hence shorter. I do not need or want to fix the zero padding.

The next part is a case reference number which immediately follows the client reference number, so using the same A00628 example it is 0002. In this case we have two issues, firstly and as might be obvious, this would eventually need two (or more) digits if the client ends up with 10 or more cases, e.g. 0011. You can also see an example of a problem which is in some cases no case number is provided at all e.g. K00976.1.81F42.pdf means client reference K00976 but there is no case reference number. If or more accurately *when* one of these is encountered I would like a case reference number of 0000 to be used.

I want to extract the client reference and store this as a variable, I want to extract the case reference and store this as a variable and if there is no case reference to default to storing 0000 as the case reference number value.

I feel the desired solution should cope with variable numbers of zeros for the client reference and whilst the number of digits for the case reference number *seems* to be consistent, the number of leading zeros is not based on how many cases that client has raised. It would seem the way to 'find' the case reference would be to find the first fullstop and work backwards four numeric digits and therefore obtain the full case reference number. If a file name has as per the example of K00976.1.81F42.pdf no case reference number then this *should* fail and the value 0000 be used instead.

I don't need to do anything with regards to the rest of the file name. So using the above example list the desired results would be -

| Client Ref | Case Ref |
| --- | --- |
| A00628 | 0002 |
| A00628 | 0002 |
| A00628 | 0002 |
| A00628 | 0002 |
| A1296 | 0004 |
| K00976 | 0000 |

I don't have any personal preference as to what tools are used e.g. sed, awk, etc. but this is straining my limited sed knowledge.

I did get as far as the following sed command which only partially solved this problem.

echo "$var" | sed 's/000[0-9].*//g'

If we ignore the possibility of a case reference number having more than one non-zero digits, this does not cope with file names completely lacking a case number. It does otherwise extract the client reference number.

Ok, with the invaluable help of people especially @dawg I currently have the following which gets me very close to a working solution

```
find . -type f | sed -E 's|^.*/||; s|^([a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,5})(\..*$)|mkdir -p "/dest/\1/0000/" cp -p $_ "/dest/\1/0000/\1\2"|; s|^([a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,5})([0-9]{4})(\..*$)|mkdir -p "/dest/\1/\2/" cp -p $_ "/dest/\1/\2/\1\2\3"|;'
```

This produces as examples the following result

```
mkdir -p "/dest/N00526/0000/"; cp -p "/dest/N00526/0000/N00526.2.5AAC3.pdf"
mkdir -p "/dest/L00872/0001/"; cp -p "/dest/L00872/0001/L008720001.63.A89F2.pdf"
mkdir -p "/dest/V00304/0002/"; cp -p "/dest/V00304/0002/V003040002.28.5C249.pdf"
mkdir -p "/dest/P00767/0001/"; cp -p "/dest/P00767/0001/P007670001.23.DED34.pdf"
mkdir -p "/dest/P00767/0000/"; cp -p "/dest/P00767/0000/P00767.16.6D859.pdf"
```

The final piece I need is to include in the above the original file path so here is what one line needs to look like -

```
mkdir -p "/dest/P00767/0000/"; cp -p "/source/subfolder/P00767.16.6D859.pdf" "/dest/P00767/0000/P00767.16.6D859.pdf"
```

Bonus points for then taking the completed command string and having it executed. I can however live with outputting it all to a text file and then having another command read each line and execute it.

Comment: No reason for any kind of sed or awk here at all -- shell parameter expansion and native regex matching (`[[ $string =~ $re ]]` to populate the `BASH_REMATCH` array) are quite adequate.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specifically state how we can tell if `A12960004` is a client number of `A1296` and a case number of `0004` or a client number of `A12960` and a case number of `004` or something else. Also, how do we know that `K00976` is a client number missing a case number instead of client number `K009` and case number `76` or something else? For example maybe client numbers never end in 0 or maybe case numbers are always 4 digits - there has to be SOMETHING to programmatically identify the 2 numbers.

Comment: You said "It would seem the way to 'find' the case reference would be to find the first fullstop and work backwards four numeric digits and therefore obtain the full case reference number." which would mean that in `K00976.1.81F42.pdf` the case number is `0976` and the client number is `K0` but that doesn't match your expected output or other statements about that case.

Comment: I have got a lot further - see my edited question. However I am now stuck on how to include the original file path in my sed generated result. With the additional information you can better see what my end goal is. That is to decode the file name and move files to sub-folders based on info extracted from the file name. @dawg or anyone - if someone can post this final bit as an answer I can upvote your solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given these file names:

```
$ ls -1 *
A006280002.40.D7A5A.msg
A006280002.41.C7E4E.msg
A006280002.42.16362.msg
A006280002.43.C4048.msg
A12960004.1.4D6AC.xls
K00976.1.81F42.pdf
```

You can loop over the files and split with GNU awk (for match with capture groups) and assign to two bash variables like so:

```
for fn in *; do
    read -r client case <<<"$(echo "$fn" | gawk -F. '{
                            match($1,/^([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)([0-9]*).*$/,m)
                            if (m[2]) print (m[1],m[2]) 
                            else print (m[1],"0000")}')"
    echo "$fn => $client | $case"                            
done
```

Or entirely in Bash:

```
for fn in *; do
    [[ $fn =~ ^([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)([0-9]*) ]] || continue
    client="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]] then
        case="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    else
        case="0000"    
    fi        
    echo "$fn => $client | $case"
done  
# If zsh replace BASH_REMATCH[] with match[]
```

Either prints:

```
A006280002.40.D7A5A.msg => A00628 | 0002
A006280002.41.C7E4E.msg => A00628 | 0002
A006280002.42.16362.msg => A00628 | 0002
A006280002.43.C4048.msg => A00628 | 0002
A12960004.1.4D6AC.xls => A1296 | 0004
K00976.1.81F42.pdf => K00976 | 0000
```

If you want just the text with `'0000'` if the case is not found, you can use this `sed`:

```
printf "%s\n" * | sed -E 's/^([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)\..*$/\10000/; s/^([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)([0-9]*).*$/\1 | \2/'
```

Prints:

```
A00628 | 0002
A00628 | 0002
A00628 | 0002
A00628 | 0002
A1296 | 0004
K00976 | 0000
```

Which can be further parsed in the shell easily to constituent parts...

---

To use `find` (and assuming the same list of files...):

Only `sed`:

```
find . -type f | sed -E 's|^.*/||; s/([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)\..*$/\10000/; s/^([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)([0-9]*).*$/\1 | \2/'
```

In a shell loop:

```
while read -r client case; do
    echo "$client | $case"
done < <(find . -type f | sed -E 's|^.*/||; s/([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)\..*$/\10000/; s/^([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)([0-9]*).*$/\1 \2/')
```

Comment: Your answer looks promising @dawg however the source list of file names will be in my case generated from using the find command and I then need to send it to awk. I am ideally going to do this on a Mac which does not have gawk installed but it looks like the Mac awk may have the same capabilities. The following page seems to match the built-in man page on a Mac. https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/awk/

Comment: See edit for MacOS solution...

Comment: Thanks again @dawg the single line find/sed works, the shell loop gives an error. Also it looks like the sed one at least is failing on some names e.g. P010370001 .1.A5D13.pdf results in P01 | 0370001 and should result in P0103 | 0001

Comment: *sed one at least is failing on some names e.g. P010370001 .1.A5D13.pdf results in P01 | 0370001 and should result in P0103 | 0001* You need to be more specific on what is meat vs what is bone -- What happens to the `7` for instance? Is is just a matter of `[A-Z]` and then a fixed number of digits for the client? That is easy fix...

Comment: If a client + case of `A00628 | 0002` comes from `A006280002` then a client + case of `A00620 | 0002` comes from `A006200002` but, unless I'm misreading it, your code would split `A006200002` into client + case `A0062 | 00002` since it won't allow for client numbers that end in `0`. It'd also fail for `A102030009.foo`. The OP hasn't told us how to accurately identify client vs case numbers yet.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, I interpreted the 'delimiter' between client and case as `(^[A-Z]0*[1-9]+)(0+[0-9]*)` -- ie, the first 0 after the client. It *may* be that the client is just a fixed number of digits but the OP has not confirmed that (and I am not gonna play the *what about this then?* game...) If it is a fixed number of digits then we can just use parameter expansion on the file names.

Comment: Right, but I don't see any reason to think that the client number cannot contain or end in 0 and they've already told us it's not a fixed number of digits (but they've also told us the case number IS a fixed 4 digit string before the first `.` but then include the case `K00976` in their example where that's not true). If the OPs problem is solvable then there has to be some other criteria they haven't told us about yet, and I don't think we could guess at from the question, that separates client from case number.

Comment: The case number comes after the client number. The client number as stated can be variable length but it looks like the case number is a consistent 4 numeric digits followed by a full-stop followed by at least one numeric digit so 0002.40, 0002.41, 0002.42, 0002.43, 0004.1 and 0001.1 would all be possible, with the full-stop not actually part of case number. Plus the possibility of NO case number at all as previously discussed. The following may get closer - (^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,5})\.|(^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,5})([0-9]{4})

Comment: Many thanks everyone for your contributions, especially @dawg I think I now have something that gets me to where I need to be as follows. find . -type f | sed -E 's|^.*/||; s/^([a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,5})(\..*$)/\1 | 0000 | \1\2/; s/^([a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,5})([0-9]{4})(\..*$)/\1 | \2 | \1\2\3/;'

Answer (score 0):

Simplify @dawg answer (too long for a comment):

```
printf '%s\n' * | gawk -F. '{
    match($1,/^([A-Z]0*[1-9]*)([0-9]*).*$/,m)
    printf "%s => ", $0
    if (m[2]) print m[1] " | " m[2]
    else print m[1] " |  0000"
}'
```

Comment: My understanding is that OP wanted the values in shell variables. Maybe not, but if so this will be longer to achieve that goal...

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928233/extracting-fields-and-striping-substrings#comment137391235_77928451).